# My Facebook Newsfeed is stuck on only 2 posts on my Mac but ok on the iPad

Tags: facebook

I can only get 2 posts on my FB newsfeed on my Mac (more stories doesn't work) 
but normal scrolling if I use the iPad. Can anyone help?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't clear that it's a web application question and it's a troubleshooting problem with little benefit to the community and reflects the platform 5 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Standard troubleshooting:

- clear caches and cookies
- check for any plugins interfering, or any browser updates pending
- try another browser
- log in and out again

Answer (score 1):

Click on News Feed in the top left corner, tick Most Recent instead of Top Stories. This should do the trick. If you use a thumbnail to login to Facebook, you will need to create a new thumbnail using the URL facebook.com/?sk=h_chr to set Most Recent  as a default.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this is a browser issue.
Try clearing your browser's cookies and cache. This might fix the issue.